# Creating a new Directory structure from a text file. PS. I am not a programmer, just need assistance

Tags: database

Below is a text file representing a small part of the structure that I wish to create.
The first comma delimiter represents the Folder and Sub Folders that I wish to create under a top level Folder called DATABASE DATA.
The second comma delimiter represents the File Name.
The third comma delimiter represents the location of the files to export into the new Folder structure.

```
"File Samples\Type\Multi Page Scans,""DemoScan 06-12-2009 10-44-58.tif"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\multi page scans\demoscan 06-12-2009 10-44-58.tif"""
"File Samples\Type\Multi Page Scans,""gc-p-01-l.tif"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\multi page scans\gc-p-01-l.tif"""
"File Samples\Type\Multi Page Scans,""95_02036_003.tif"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\multi page scans\95_02036_003.tif"""
"File Samples\Type\Multi Page Scans,""milk cart.jpg"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\multi page scans\milk cart.jpg"""
"File Samples\Type\Multi Page Scans,""15_1.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\multi page scans\15_1.tif\15_1.tif"""
"File Samples\Type\Colour Scans,""montage.bmp"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\colour scans\montage.bmp"""
"File Samples\Type\Colour Scans,""NIAGRA.jpeg"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\colour scans\niagra.jpg"""
"File Samples\Type\Colour Scans,""Welcome Scan.jpg"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\colour scans\welcome scan.jpg"""
"File Samples\Type\Colour Scans,""SHOOTAA.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\colour scans\shootaa.tif"""
"File Samples\Type\Colour Scans,""jamesc.bmp"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\colour scans\jamesc.bmp"""
"File Samples\Type\Colour Scans,""teeth.jpg"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\colour scans\teeth.jpg"""
"File Samples\Type\MS Office Documents,""KUNDI  DAN 1.docx"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\ms office documents\kundi  dan 1.docx"""
"File Samples\Type\MS Office Documents,""Save & Invest.doc"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\ms office documents\save & invest.rtf"""
"File Samples\Type\MS Office Documents,""2003.05.01 Scanning Index.csv"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\ms office documents\2003.05.01 scanning index.csv"""
"File Samples\Type\MS Office Documents,""ec customer breakdown.xls"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\ms office documents\ec customer breakdown.xlsx"""
"File Samples\Type\PDF Files,""alchemy_database_white_paper.pdf"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\pdf files\alchemy_database_white_paper.pdf"""
"File Samples\Type\PDF Files,""Kuhl1InsuranceCS.pdf"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\pdf files\kuhl1insurancecs.pdf"""
"File Samples\Type\PDF Files,""NewportBeach_CaseStudy1.pdf"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\pdf files\newportbeach_casestudy1.pdf"""
"File Samples\Type\PDF Files,""SpaceStation_CaseStudy_031103.pdf"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\pdf files\spacestation_casestudy_031103.pdf"""
"File Samples\Type\PDF Files,""Alchemy First.pdf"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\pdf files\alchemy first.pdf"""
"File Samples\Type\Mainframe Data,""bidtabam3.doc"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\mainframe data\bidtabam3.doc"""
"File Samples\Type\Mainframe Data,""bidtabpm5.doc"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\mainframe data\bidtabpm5.doc"""
"File Samples\Type\Mainframe Data,""award04.doc"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\mainframe data\award04.doc"""
"File Samples\Type\Mainframe Data,""award02.doc"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\file samples\type\mainframe data\award02.doc"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Members,""Members_428.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\zonal scans - members\members_428.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Members,""Members_431.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\zonal scans - members\members_431.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Members,""Members_432.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\zonal scans - members\members_432.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Members,""Members_435.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\zonal scans - members\members_435.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Members,""Members_436.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\zonal scans - members\members_436.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Invoices,""Invoices354.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\demos\invoices354.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Invoices,""Invoices355.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\demos\invoices355.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Invoices,""Invoices356.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\demos\invoices356.tif"""
"Demo Scans\Zonal Scans - Invoices,""Invoices357.TIF"",""c:\users\fss\desktop\filecenter data\demo scans\demos\invoices357.tif"""
```

Comment: So it looks like this is your first posting at StackOverFlow.  Welcome.  With that said, you will probably want to review [the guidelines for appropriate questions for this site.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Unfortunately your question as currently asked leaves us trying to figure out what you are talking about.  1) We don't know what Operating System you want to create these directories (Linux, Windows, Mac)?  2) We don't have the big picture of where this is going, nor where text data is coming from. 3) What's the goal here (in simple, really simple terms)?

Comment: The OS is Windows 7, Need to create a Folder structure and include the files relative to this structure. The text data (above) will be in a .bat file or similar. I need to move data from a database into a folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you say you want, but this seems more than fragile. Many of us could write a script to take that file as an input, scan it and create a directory tree utilizing the first "element" in that data file, e.g. `File Samples\Type\Multi Page Scans`

This could be done in a DOS style batch file, but I think I'd probably use python with the sys / re / os / shutil / commands libraries.  That way the conversion would work in any operating system.

But there are a few issues.

1. The data above is poorly formed.  It's not clean Comma Separated Variables (CSV) content.  The quotation marks are all fudged up.  We can work with that, but it makes me believe that that could easily change in the future.  If that happens, any code written now breaks immediately.
2. I still have no clue where you are going.  The reason folks automate tasks (like yours) is to make life easier.  So now we have created directories easily and quickly.  What's the next step?  I'm going to guess you are going to want to use those newly created directories and stick something in there.  And that step will be ridiculously time consuming.  It's not at all clear on how you intend to do that, but what I see are five more new stackoverflow problems coming from you, sigh.
3. StackOverflow is not a way to get around bidding a job to a developer.  It's a system to answer programming related questions.
4. I will offer one recommendation.  Its time for you to learn a programming language.  For creating directories, almost anything would work.  Php / Python / Ruby / C++ / Java / JavaScript using node.  Pick one, watch a few youtube videos, take a free beginners tutorial, have some fun.  Here's a [free course from Google (Python)](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) which I only mention because the last lesson is about utilities (the skill you need for your problem above)  The really awesome thing about this step is everything here is free.. the tutorials, the videos, the tools to use the language and the language itself.
5. You've not told us what the database system is. If you are using MySQL there are some tools available that connect the online database directly to plugins in Excel, that are pretty amazing.  No programming required.  It's possible such tools exist for your database.

Edit your original problem statement to better represent your question.  Include the stuff from your note.  (Remove `PS I'm not a developer...` from the title..)  We can pretty much figure that out as you didn't include any language tags in your problem statement.